# Howto use NOW() function in MySQL Workbench UI to get a date for a new record

Tags: windows, user-interface, mysql-workbench

Simple question: What is the trick needed to be able to use the `NOW()` function directly in *MySQL Workbench* (v.8) UI, *Result Grid* panel, so when the *Apply* button is pressed and the changes submitted, the resulting field has this kind of date *2020-06-27 00:03:57*?

[image: MySQL Workbench 8 Result Grid]

If I just type `NOW()` in the cell, I got the following error:

> ERROR 1292: 1292: Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'created_at' at row 1

It seems to me it is interpreting it as a string...
Once I have accomplished this with MW v.6 but I just forgot how and I can't find where I read how this is done...

I also tried `NOW()' and `´NOW()´` and even `STR_TO_DATE(NOW())` but I just can't remember how it is done. (I know I can use an update statement, etc. but I want to be able to do it using the UI, just for the convenience for those quick tests...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typing simple now() is interpreted as text
use

```
\func now()
```

Comment: You win! It was a matter of minutes mini race. It was an easy one, right? I just couldn't remember/find it! Now it's in QA format for posterity. Thanks again

Comment: I had been searching for this same question/answer for a while... thanks @Vikash Agrawal